# Dimension theorem (in infinite dimension) - all basis of any vector space have the same cardinality.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

I am reading a note from author Justin Tatch Moore, in which he proves the Dimension Theorem, which says that all the basis of a vector space have the same cardinality (in infinite dimension), using Zorn's Lemma. The text can be found [HERE!](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.121.03.260.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A14b13f81039c5bfad82920604cbe4e2b)

The idea is basically as follows: suppose that $A$ and $B$ are basis of the vector space $V$, and define $P$ to be the set consisting of all linear transformations $T$ from a subspace $W$ of
$V$ onto $W$ such that:

1. $A \cap W$ and $B \cap W$ are each a basis for $W$, and
2. the restriction of $T$ to $A \cap W$ is a bijection between $A \cap W$ and $B \cap W.$

then we show using Zorn's Lemma that $P$ has a maximal element, which is a transformation
$ T: W \rightarrow W $ with the properties (1) and (2). Note that if we show that $ W = V $, the theorem ends due to the propertie (2). Hence to do this the argument starts as in the figure below

[image]

My question is how to build two sets of sequences with the above four properties? The first two properties seem very reasonable, but the last two I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by induction.

Suppose $W$ is a proper subspace of $V$. Then $W$ can't contain $A$ so fix $a_{1}$ in $A$ which is not in $W$. Set $A_{1}=\{a_{1}\}$. Then $A_{1}$ is not contained in $W$.

Now for the induction hypothesis let $n\geq 1$ be given and assume we have constructed $A_{i}$ for $i\leq n$ and $B_{i}$ for $i<n$.

For the induction step we build $B_{n}$ first and then $A_{n+1}$.

Since $B$ is a basis for $V$, $A_{n}$ is contained in the span of $B$. Since $A_{n}$ is finite we only need a finite amount of $B$ to span all of $A_{n}$. In other words there is a finite subset $B'$ of $B$ such that $A_n$ is contained in the span of $B'$. So for our $B_{n}$ we can choose $B'\cup B_{n-1}$ (and if $n=1$ then say $B_{0}=\emptyset$). Note that we include $B_{n-1}$ in the union to make sure the sequence increases.

Now for $A_{n+1}$. By the same argument, $A$ has a finite subset $A'$ such that $B_{n}$ is contained in the span of $A'$. If $A_n\cup W$ spans $V$ then don't worry about making $A_{n+1}$ properly contain $A_n$, and just let $A_{n+1}=A'\cup A_{n}$. However if $A_{n}   \cup W$ doesn't span $V$ then, as $A$ is a basis for $V$, there must be some $v$ in $A$ that is not in $A_{n}\cup W$ so not in $A_{n}$ in particular. Now if $A_{n+1}=A'\cup A_{n}\cup\{v\}$ then we are ensured that $A_{n+1}$ properly contains $A_{n}$.